# I deleted Ubuntu for VirtualBox by accident

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, homestead

I need to run VirtualBox so I can use homestead. However, when I was cleaning my computer, I accidentally deleted the ubuntu-16.04-amd64-disk001.vmdk. How would I fix that? When I download ubuntu from this link (http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/), where would I place the downloaded ubuntu? I apologize, I am a beginner at using this.

Edit(No input file specified):
I did "vagrant box remove laravel/homestead --all" followed by "vagrant box add laravel/homestead". I vagranted up (as shown in the first two pics below). However, when I went on chrome to the url that normally displays my website, it says "No file input specified"(as shown below in the 3rd picture). I also included a photo of what my virtualBox looks like in the 4th picture.

[image: Terminal After Vagrant Up Pt 1]

[image: Terminal After Vagrant Up Pt 2]

[image: No Input Specified]

[image: Picture of Virtual Box]

Comment: I think it may be easiest to save your `homestead.yaml` file, destroy the box completely, and then set up a new one, using configurations from your saved `homestead.yaml`. Do you have any important information (e.g. some data in the DB) that you need to recover?

Comment: No I do not have any important information in the database! So basically I would just redownload virtualbox and then replace the new homestead.yaml file with my old homestead. yaml?

Comment: Try to first run 'vagrant destroy --force', and then `vagrant up`. If this doesn't work, then try  `vagrant box remove laravel/homestead` followed by `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` and `vagrant up`.

Comment: I encountered some errors after removing the homestead folder and installing a new one. :(

Comment: I think it won't matter too much if you cloned a fresh version of Homestead. What we need to fix here is the vagrant box itself (remove the 'broken' box, and add a new one). Have you tried the commands I mentioned above?

Comment: That definetly helped, because now I can run "vagrant up", so thank you! However, when I try to access my website my typing "market.test" into chrome,  I received "No input file specified". (I described the situation in more details above)

Comment: have you modified your `hosts` file? If you don't know what it is, just google it. It's really easy, but has to be done for each site separately.

Answer (score -1):

Complete image files are kinda extensive files of several gigabytes, so my guess is that is was removed from your computer (a.k.a "Beyond the Graveyard") and it is not available on Recycle Bin. You can try a deleted file recovery software like Recuva, although most of them are subscription paid (around $50 USD for 1 year) that might try to recover the file if that memory area has not been reused already. Another recommendation, or this is what I do, is place the image file on a new partition of my drive (or a second drive if you have one) to avoid any future issues, on my work I run these virtual images from my root drive (C:) where I have a folder for each version of a OS I work with. Hope this helps.